# Deploying my Django app on CentOS, styles stopped loading

Tags: css, django, centos7

I have a Django 1.11 app that I want to deploy on a CentOS 7 server, which I access via a terminal from my Ubuntu 16.10 guest on Windows 10 host through Virtualbox 5.1.18.

After reconstructing my working environment on CentOS and cloning the repository I decided to run a development server to check if all python packages have been successfully installed and loaded (I went for python manage.py runserver 0:0:0:8000 to be able to connect to the app from Ubuntu guest).

My problem is the following - although the app works fine, for some reason **the app on CentOS does not "see" the .css files**, which results in styles not being loaded. I double-checked that the files are there, and in settings.py I have:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

So the relative paths have not changed and yet the styles are not loaded on CentOS while they work perfectly well on Ubuntu.

**Anyone knows how to fix the problem and what caused it?**

**EDIT:**
Since there was no helpful answer or comment I now deployed the application using uwsgi and nginx and the problem obviously persists. Will I get a helpful answer now please?

**UPDATE:**
Thanks to Haroldo_OK I realized that probably what's at fault is the way the frontend was developed:

```
<head>
      <base href="http://127.0.0.1:8000" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/cover.css' %}">

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Kontakt</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="../../assets/css/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="cover.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

Anyone knows how should I change it and what should I download and where to put it for a fix? I really have no clue about frontend...

Comment: What does it have to do with server being killed? It's not being killed, it just does not load the .css

Notice that the development server I run from Ubuntu DOES load the .css,  so I don't see how this has anything to do with it.

Comment: I did, comments included, and I'm pretty sure "It has not gone through security audits or performance tests" has nothing to do with loading .css

Comment: Try to take a look at your browser's built-in debugger, at the network tab; see which HTTP error messages appear there.

Comment: Wow, great idea, I can't believe I didn't think of that. I now see the problem: a collleague from work used some tutorial template from Django Girls / Bootstrap, and it references css from localhost. I'll post an update.

Answer (score 1):

the path to static URL should be of your hosting platform  **CentOS 7 server**

path of static URL on server is different from local

correct your static URL path

Comment: There seems to be no indication on his code that this would be the problem.